# how to know the indexes of the smallest 15 objects inside an NSMutable array and store these indexes in another array

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, for-loop, nsmutablearray

how to know the indexes of the smallest 15 objects inside an NSMutable array and store these indexes in another array
Im writing my program in objective-c, I tried using for loops but I haven't been able to come up with the proper algorithm yet.

Comment: Sort the array, the indices `0`...`14` will correspond to the smallest 15 objects.

Comment: What is the concrete problem. Iterate through your array and store the indexes of the smallest 15 values e.g. in an ordered array of 15 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to sort the array and pick the first 15 elements.

A more efficient approach is to push them through a binary heap with a cap of 15 elements. The first 15 elements from the array go straight into the heap. Every subsequent element replaces the largest element in the heap if it is smaller than it.

CoreFoundation provides [CFBinaryHeap](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFBinaryHeapRef/Reference/reference.html), which can be used for this purpose, though you'll have fun getting `id`s in and out as `void *`s. There's also [NDHeap](https://github.com/nathanday/ndheap), which I know nothing about (other than that it exists and purports to implement a binary heap).

My preference would be to use C++'s `std::priority_queue`, which is thoroughly tested and handles `id`s just fine with a bit of coaxing.

```
auto lt = [](id a, id b) { return (whatever means "a < b" to you); };
std::priority_queue<id, std::vector<id>, decltype(lt)> pq{lt};

for (id e in myarray) {
    if (pq.size() == 15 && lt(e, pq.top()))
        pq.pop();
    if (pq.size() < 15)
        pq.push(e);
}

NSMutableArray * top15 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:15];
while (!pq.empty()) {
    [top15 addObject:pq.top()];
    pq.pop();
}
```

To use this code, you will have to rename the relevant .m file to .mm.